# Android pdf view redirect

Tags: android, pdf, viewer

I have the following code that pulls a pdf document from a remote viewer to view:

```
package com.example.techvault;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class PDFFromServerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document);
        Intent in= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        String url = in.getStringExtra("full_url");
        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
            url = "http://ezdrawdocs.com" + url;
        }
        Log.d("pdf url: ",url);
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Downloader.DownloadFile(url, file);

        showPdf();
    }
    public void showPdf()
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
            List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

When the backarrow is selected it redirects to a blank screen.  How can I control which activity to redirect to when backarrow is selected?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define that in your manifest under the activity with

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.example.yourapp.SomeActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I put the code in my manifest under the activity that calls to pdf view and it still shows a blank screen.

Comment: Well, if you go back to your Activity it doesn'y go through onCreate. You should override onResume to say what must happen when you return to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is implementing what I call a "Passthrough Activity" (an Activity that has no UI and immediately launches a different Activity)... I personally try to avoid them.

That said, what you need to do is call `Activity.finish()` after `showPDF()` in `Activity.onCreate()`. That will close your passthrough so that when you back out of the PDF viewer you will not come back to the passthrough.